# What is a Darth?

Tags: star-wars, sith

Throughout Star Wars various Sith have referred to themselves as 'Darth', Darth Vader, Darth Maul, Darth Revan, etc. I learned from [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/218560/difference-between-darth-and-lord) that a Darth was seen as greater than a Sith Lord in legends, which made me wonder, what exactly does the title mean? What is the difference between 'Bob who is a Sith' and 'Darth Bob'?

Comment: It's a title/rank, same as any other title or rank.

Comment: There's a pretty good explanation in an answer here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/36335/the-use-of-darth-as-vaders-name-not-title-in-star-wars?rq=1

Comment: The difference is Darth Bob is a badass. You do not mess with him.